Firebase- Failed to write data into realtime database for a web app
I have have created a simple form to store email address into the realtime database (test mode) that created on the Firebase Console.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <form style="border:1px solid #ccc">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
      <hr>

      <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required id="email">

      <script type="module">
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.0/firebase-app.js";
        import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.0/firebase-analytics.js";
        import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.0/firebase-database.js";

        // Your Firebase configuration...

        const firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "data",
          authDomain: "data",
          databaseURL: "data",
          projectId: "data",
          storageBucket: "data",
          messagingSenderId: "data",
          appId: "data",
          measurementId: "data"
        };

        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const database = getDatabase(app);

        const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

        function storeData() {
          const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
          const reference = ref(database, "signup/")
          set(reference, {
            email: email
          });
        }
      </script>


      <button class="signupbtn" onclick="storeData()">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    <!--</div>-->
  </form>






</body>

</html>

As per tutorial, I installed firebase(version 13.7.2) on my windows OS using npm. However, no data is written in the database that I created. I would like to know what could be the problem and how to fix it?

Are you seeing errors in the browser console? And are you sure the security rules are correct? I remember when you select in Firebase test mode, which allows all read write, it will automatically expire after a duration that your database is safe again.

the error I get is "Denying load of . Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension."

the database rule is ({
"rules": {
".read": "true",  // 2024-5-15
".write": "true",  // 2024-5-15
}
})

Can you try the following code and give me some feedback?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Firebase Example</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <script type="module">
    import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.0/firebase-app.js';
    import { getAnalytics } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.0/firebase-analytics.js';
    import { getDatabase, ref, set } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.0/firebase-database.js';

    // Your Firebase configuration
    const firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "data",
          authDomain: "data",
          databaseURL: "data",
          projectId: "data",
          storageBucket: "data",
          messagingSenderId: "data",
          appId: "data",
          measurementId: "data"
    };

    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
    const database = getDatabase(app);

    function storeData() {
      const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
      const reference = ref(database, "signup/");
      set(reference, {
        email: email
      }).then(() => {
        console.log("Data stored successfully!");
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error storing data: ", error);
      });
    }
    document.getElementById('sign-btn').addEventListener('click', storeData);
  </script>
</head>


<body>
  <form style="border:1px solid #ccc">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
      <hr>

      <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required id="email">

      <button type="button" id="sign-btn" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>


It worked. Data stored successfully!
Thank you very much!
Can you tell me what was the problem in the code that I provided?

storeData() was not defined globally as it is within a module

I just move the script code from firebase into the html head tag. The function storeData() can't be called from onclick when its in the head so i just add an addEventListener. However, I recommend you create a second script file where you import all the script code so that your html file is not too big.
Btw don't forget to mark my answer as Solved so other users can see directly that you found a solution.
